# Reference Request: Adjoint State Method for ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I would like to understand the Adjoint State Method for ODEs of the form
\begin{equation}
\dot{z}(t) = f(z(t),t,\theta),\quad t\in[0,T],
\end{equation}
where is a set of parameters. However I can't seem to find a good (mathematically rigorous) source nor even a youtube video, that explains it well. Can someone help me out?

Also: I know that one wants to compute $\partial_\theta L(z(T),\theta)$, where $L$ is some suitable loss function. Is there also a version of this method, where one has $\theta$ itself being a function of time? I suppose one then would like to find the Fréchet-derivative of $L$ w.r.t. $\theta$.

Any source on these questions would be helpful.

Comment: Pontrjagin's maximum principle, Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equations?

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. Do I understand correctly, that in Pontrjagin's maximum principle, the $\theta$ is already time-dependent?

Comment: I was more asking about the context, it could also be none-of-above.

Comment: I am currently reading this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366

Supposedly they use the adjoint state method to train their model. And I haven't heard of this method before; hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### one single small jump in an ODE solution

The general idea is that you take any solution $z(t)$. Then select some time $0< \tau<T$. Stop the integration at time $t=\tau$ and and add some very small perturbation $\delta z(\tau)$ to the value $z(\tau)$ there. Now observe the evolution of the perturbed solution $\tilde z(t)$. In first order you get $\tilde z(t)-z(t)\approx δz(t)$ which follows the linear DE
$$
δ\dot z(t) = \partial_zf(z(t),t,θ)δz(t)\implies δz(T)=K(T,τ)δz(τ).
$$
where $t\mapsto K(t,τ)$ is the fundamental matrix of basis solutions of the linear DE, esp. $K(τ,τ)=I$.

With its definition as fundamental matrix and the semi-group property $K(T,τ)=K(T,t)K(t,τ)$ one can give their differential equations
$$
\frac{d}{dt}K(t,τ)=∂_zf(z(t),t,θ)K(t,τ),\\
\frac{d}{dt}K(T,t)=-K(T,t)∂_zf(z(t),t,θ).
$$

#### adjoint = back propagation of gradients

The idea now is that if you have a target function $L(z(T),θ)$ then its change under the perturbation is
$$
L(z(T)+δz(T),θ)-L(z(T),θ)
\approx δL(z(T),θ)=∂_zL(z(T),θ)δz(T)=∂_zL(z(T),θ)K(T,τ)δz(τ)
$$
Now one can define (the row vector)
$$
p(t)=∂_zL(z(T),θ)K(T,t)\implies \dot p(t)=-p(t)∂_zf(z(t),t,θ).
$$
The overall identity that was established is that
$$
p(T)δz(T)=p(t)δz(t)=p(τ)δz(τ),
$$
so $p$ allows, in first order, to estimate what a change at time $τ$ has on the target function $L$ at time $T$. In light of this pairing property $p$ is called the adjoint solution.

#### continuous perturbation through parameter change

Now if you change the parameter $θ$ to $θ+δθ$, the ODE rhs function changes in first order to
$$
f(z(t),t,θ+δθ)=f(z(t),t,θ)+∂_θf(z(t),t,θ)δθ.
$$
One could say that this additional term causes in every infinitesimal time step an additional perturbation of the solution. Or more precisely, the perturbation $δz(t)$ evolves from $t=0$, $δz(0)$ per
$$
δ\dot z(t) = \partial_zf(z(t),t,θ)δz(t)+∂_θf(z(t),t,θ)δθ
$$
Multiply left with $p(t)$ as kind-of integrating factor to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(p(t)δz(t))=p(t)∂_θf(z(t),t,θ)δθ\\
p(T)δz(T)=0+\int_0^T p(t)∂_θf(z(t),t,θ)\,dt\,δθ
$$
Thus the change in $L$ is in first order
$$
L(z(t)+δz(T),θ+δθ)-L(z(t),θ)=[p(T)δz(T)+∂_θL(z(t),θ)]\,δθ
$$
One is justified to call
$$
\int_0^T p(t)∂_θf(z(t),t,θ)\,dt+∂_θL(z(t),θ)
$$
the gradient (component) for $θ$.

Note that "gradient" is used here in the sense of the Jacobi matrix. A "real" gradient has the same format as the tangent vectors and is connected via $\frac{∂L}{∂u}v=\langle\nabla_uL,v\rangle$.